# Barcode scan using a portion of the camera view

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to scan a barcode and show the camera view in full screen but want to scan only when the barcode is in the centre of the square region as shown below:

[image]

Is this possible using windows phone 8?

Any tricks to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 8.1 the thing you're trying to do is available in the default Camera App it's called Bing Vision.  If you're using 8.0 you can just click on the Search button and Tap the Vision icon, which basically does the same thing.  If you want to program this functionality yourself, then it really depends on what Barcode Library you want to use.

I would recommend ZXing.  Website here: [ZXing CodeProject](http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/)

So basically you need to setup a simple camera app and create a scanning operation every few seconds or so.

01) Get the preview of the camera into a Writeable Bitmap like so

```C#
cam.GetPreviewBufferArgb32(wbitmap.Pixels);    
wbitmap.Invalidate();
// crop your bitmap to whatever that RECT is
```

02) Decode your bitmap

```C#
Result r = br.Decode(wbitmap);   // where br is your BarcodeReader
```

03) Display your Result with r.Text

Comment: Hello, thanks for the steps. I am developing my own application for this. I am already using ZXing.net library, and all works fine. One good point you mentioned is cropping the rectangle which I think will do the trick. Will try that. Thanks.