# QR Scan in Windows phone 8.1 based on WinRT

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, qr-code, windows-phone-store

In a wp project development includes QR Scan module. I was surfing for some sources regarding this, Some article says that it won't supported in wp 8.1 winrt. Some says a third party tool can achieve but still there are some issues with that. So I request to guide a best approach for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649393/barcode-scan-using-a-portion-of-the-camera-view/25657857#25657857

Comment: Do that works on wp 8.1 based on winrt?

Comment: Yeah according to their page:  They support Windows RT Class Library and Runtime Components (winmd)

Comment: Yes but I already tried this a bit, I couldn't resolve the result class.

Comment: If you can't resolve the `Result` class, then you probably installed it incorrectly.  Try using NuGet to simplify the installation progress.  If that doesn't work, then you forgot a namespace `"using ZXing;"`